# Serial port al recibir datos los junta entre si

Tags: javascript, serialport

Estoy intentando que al escanear con mi escáner, me lea un código. El código lo lee correctamente y lo envía al front-end. Utilizo el serial port y lo conecto en el puerto COM1. El problema que tengo es que cuando leo varias veces seguidas, el código que coge el escáner se junta y manda el código junto. Yo le he pedido que lo mande cuando llega a 163, y al juntarlo después de varias veces leído llega a 163 y lo manda.

```
serial.on('readable', async function() {
try {
    const data = await serial.read(163)
    serial.read().
    console.log(data.toString())
    getSerialData(io, data.toString());
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

})

Este es el código. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código me ha dado la solución:

```
let datos = ""
serial.on('data', (data) => {
    try {
        this.datos = this.datos + data

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.datos.includes('undefined')) {
                this.datos = this.datos.substring(9, this.datos.length)
            }
            if (this.datos != "") {
                console.log(datos)
                getSerialData(io, this.datos.toString());
                this.datos = ""
            }
        }, 200);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Oops');
    }
});
```